# can't map unslidable segment auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibdesignable

I have a problem:

```
error: IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: dlopen(My.app, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
My.app: can't map unslidable segment __TEXT to 0x100000000 with size 0x1050000
```

I have ImageButton control(for example):

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface ImageButton : UIControl
{
@private
    IBOutlet UIView *view 
    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBInspectable NSString *imageName;
```

As soon as I use it in Interface Builder I get the error. I can build and run app, and when I go to the view, it is rendered properly. The problem occurs when I'm in Interface Builder, where I don't have preview rendered correctly.

The condition:(http://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-239.3/src/ImageLoaderMachO.cpp?txt) didn't tell me much.

What am I missing?

Comment: has anyone solved this?